# Undefined property: stdClass::$total

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cart

I am working on adding the product values into the cart and i am using darryldecode Laravel shopping cart. 
When I try to get the image and total price from the attribute array, I get the error `Undefined property: stdClass::$total`.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function cart(Request $request , $id)
{
  // return $request;
  $cart = Cart::add([
    'id' => $request->id,
    "name" => $request->name,
    "crm"  => $request->sku,
    "quantity" => $request->qty,
    "price" => $request->price,
    "attributes" => array(["image" => $request->image] , "total" => $request->price * $request->qty) 
  ]);

  if($cart)
  {
    return redirect()->route('cart');
  }
}
```

Here is the Cart Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Cart;

class CartController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    // return Cart::getContent();
    return View('demo', [ 'cart' => Cart::getContent()]);
  }
}
```

Here is the view where I try to print the image and total

```
@foreach($cart as $product)
Name:<td>{{ $product->name}}</td>
Price:<td>{{ $product->price}}</td>
Quantity:<td>{{ $product->qty}}</td>
Attributes:<td>{{ $product->attributes}}</td>
@foreach(json_decode($product->attributes) as $details)
Image:<td>{{ $details->image}}</td>
Total:<td>{{ $details->total}}</td>
{{ $details}}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Inside Attributes there is an image and total price: Attributes:{"image":"glassfilms\/November2019\/ZBCUG09ms5Gvbx6rC4Ad.png","total":4440}

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this line:

```
"attributes" => array(["image" => $request->image] , "total" => $request->price * $request->qty)
```

Rather do this:

```
"attributes" => ["image" => $request->image, "total" => $request->price * $request->qty]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both attributes into one array when you want get into view (blade) file.

Use below code:

```
 $cart = Cart::add([
    'id' => $request->id,
    "name" => $request->name,
    "crm"  => $request->sku,
    "quantity" => $request->qty,
    "price" => $request->price,
    "attributes" => array(["image" => $request->image, "total" => $request->price * $request->qty]) 
  ]);
```